# @at-root directive not recognized by VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I'm editing an existing Sass project, in the mixin.scss file I find the following:

```
//elements get appended with "__" and the $name
@mixin e($name) {
  @at-root &__#{$name} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

That seems correct to me, but Visual Studio 2013 intellisense and compiler gives me an error:

```
"at-root is not a valid @ directive"
```

Comment: Are you certain you're using a version of Sass that supports `@at-root`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Web Essentials uses libsass to compile SASS files to CSS.  Unfortunately libsass does not yet support version 3.3 which is when `@at-root` was introduced.

See this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/353) for more info.